# Phoenix Introduction to Ecto Not Working

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I was following the instructions given on [this website](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/getting-started.html). I was able to generate an Elixir application using this command `mix new friends --sup` which worked.

I kept following the instructions up to [this point](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/getting-started.html#inserting-data), which returned this error on Command Prompt.

```
en** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
:erlang.send(Friends.Repo.Pool, {:"$gen_cast", {:cancel_waiting, #Reference<0.3029264411.997982211.19061>}}, [:noconnect])
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:423: :gen_server.do_send/2
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:234: :gen_server.do_cast/2
(poolboy) c:/xampp/htdocs/devup/friends/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:58: :poolboy.checkout/3
(db_connection) lib/db_connection/poolboy.ex:41: DBConnection.Poolboy.checkout/2
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:920: DBConnection.checkout/2
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:742: DBConnection.run/3
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:584: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok thanks i'll take note next time

Comment: can you show us the exact line you tried using that got this error?

Comment: at this cmd Friends.Repo.insert(person)

Comment: i solved the problem my supervisor was placed in the wrong file considering i was using the latest version of elixir